# what are the gcr-analysis topics and subscriptions?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

recently (a few days since this week of 1/9/2017) I found my GCP
projects have some gcr.io topics and gcr-analysis subscriptions show up, I
asked the team found nobody is aware or intentionally doing this and I found these topics/subscriptions show up in my other GCP project as well, so it could come from Google side? what are these used for?

```
┬───────────────────────────────────────────────┬────────────────────────────┬──────┬──────────────┐
│                  SUBSCRIPTION                 │           TOPIC            │ TYPE │ ACK_DEADLINE │
┼───────────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────────────────────┼──────┼──────────────┤
│ gcr-analysis-3b4ce76f2d36c285601b0cb46a61932c │ asia.gcr.io%2Fproject-name │ PUSH │ 10           │
│ gcr-analysis-5023e58ee7a5ff3423b5b4badadfc07a │ us.gcr.io%2Fproject-name   │ PUSH │ 10           │
│ gcr-analysis-c2be8611b9a6872cba44ab5c521af795 │ gcr.io%2Fproject-name      │ PUSH │ 10           │
│ gcr-analysis-c37057c7a14f8c0576b3b491030742d1 │ eu.gcr.io%2Fproject-name   │ PUSH │ 10           │
┴───────────────────────────────────────────────┴────────────────────────────┴──────┴──────────────┘
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are topics and subscriptions created automatically by [Google Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/), used to discover when new images are pushed. The use is described in the ["Google App Engine Flexible Environment" section](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/using-with-google-cloud-platform).

Comment: have you seen some of Google's official announcement? if possible, can Google make them to be hidden from users perspective; I'm getting used to see only topics / subscriptions created by my program only, other names were concerning us to check if our GCP projects were hacked or something unexpected

Comment: I'm aware of gcr means Google's Container Registry, but for what purpose Google needs to do these gcr-analysis since this week?

Comment: "Note: App Engine and Container Builder create Cloud Pub/Sub topics and subscriptions in your project for use in Google's internal analysis and maintenance of your container images." Documented here: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/using-with-google-cloud-platform